# I get broken image icon when displaying image from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

my question is why do I get broken image icon instead of the image from the database on my output on menu.php? and how do I get rid of it? thank you!

this is the menu.php codes where the image should be displayed

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","facility");
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE IDNo = 11";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo '<tr><td>
<img src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row ['Image']). '"/>
</td>  </tr> ';} 

?>
```

and this is my users.add.php where my upload to database codes are. the uploading of image is working fine but it just does not display the image on menu.php.

```
         $Image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['name']);
                        $ImageLoc = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']
              ['name']);
                        $imagesize = getimagesize($_FILES['image']
               ['tmp_name']);
                        $target = "upload/".basename($Image);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){

    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Failed to upload image");
    }


    if (count($errorMessage) <= 0) {

        // save to database
        $data = [
            'IDNo' => $IDNo,
            'FullName' => $FullName,
            'username' => $Username,
            'Type' => $Type,
            'Dept' => $Dept,
            'Password' => $Password,
            'Email' => $Email,
            'Role' => $Role,
            'Image' => $Image,
            'ImageLoc' => $ImageLoc,
        ];
        $id = $mysql->insert('user', $data); 

        $_SESSION['message'] = "Successfully added $FullName";
        header('location: users.php');



        if(isset($_POST['Type'])){
        $Type = e($_POST['Type']);
        $query = "INSERT INTO user (IDNo , FullName , username , Type , Dept , Password , Email , Role , Image , ImageLoc) 
        VALUES('$IDNo', '$FullName', '$username', '$Type', '$Dept', '$Password', '$Email','$Role' , '$Image' , '$ImageLoc')";

        mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $_SESSION['success']  = "New user successfully created!!";
        header('location: users.php');
    } else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO user (IDNo , FullName , username , Type , Dept , Password , Email , Role , Image , ImageLoc) 
        VALUES('$IDNo', '$FullName', '$Username', '$Type', '$Dept', '$Password', '$Email','$Role' , '$Image' , '$ImageLoc')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);


}
}
```

Comment: Is the Image column of type blob in the database? If not binary files may be altered or truncated. Try saving as base64 (instead of binary) in a text column or as binary in a blob column

Comment: this is wide open to sql injection. Also, I can't help but think that you are not actually capturing the image data correctly - read the file contents after `move_uploaded_file` - and is that a function simply called `e`??

Comment: 1. Don't use evil 'select *'. Identify the columns you actually want returned